# How do you get UIElements from ItemsControl using a DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a `StackPanel` that was made with a `ItemsControl` and `DataTemplate` using an `ItemSource` of objects.

I know how to get the list of objects from the `ItemsControl` in the `StackPanel`: `itemsControl.Items`

But, now I'd like to get the `UIElement`s associated with these `Items`.

If we have a `StackPanel` like this:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="BrandButtonsStackPanel" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <StackPanel.Children>
         <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Bind model:BrandMaintainer.VisibleBrands, Mode=OneWay}">
              <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:BrandInfo">
                      <Button Tag="{Binding SectionId, Mode=OneWay}" />
                  </DataTemplate>
              </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel.Children>
</StackPanel>
```

I tried this method but it's giving me a `null` value. I can visually see all my buttons generated at runtime:

`var brandButton = (Button)itemsControl.ContainerFromItem(itemIndex);`

Any ideas? Or is there a better way?

Thanks

EDIT: This states that a FindChildren method exists for UWP. But I'm not seeing it...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper

Comment: I need the `Button` elements to to tests on it against a `ScrollViewer`

Comment: @Clemens your method is also returning a `null` pointer on index 0. I have `Items` in my `ItemsControl` so idk whats wrong.

Comment: @Clemens So `.Content` is actually giving my the Item object not the `UIElement`.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following extension method

```
public static IEnumerable<UIElement> GetChildren(this ItemsControl itemsControl)
{
    foreach(var item in itemsControl.Items)
    {
        yield return (UIElement) itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
    }
}
```

which you can then call like this to access your wanted button

```
var brandButton = (Button) (itemsControl.GetChildren().ToList()[itemIndex]);
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: I got a flag that said this is obsolete: `ItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem` and I'm having issues using `ContainerFromItem` it returns null on me..

Comment: @visc I had a spelling error saying `ItemsControl` instead of  `itemsControl` in the loop body; does it work for you now? I don't get an obsolete warning.

Comment: @visc as for the return value, please provide a more complete example with the binding and the items source so that we can check and debug.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 
`BrandButtonsStackPanel.FindVisualChildren<Button>();`

To get all the details of buttons in a list you can use this

`List<Button> btnList=BrandButtonsStackPanel.FindVisualChildren<Button>().ToList();`